# Interpretation of “ Time as a stuff can be wasted” in Sandburg's A Father to His Son

Tags: poetry, interpretation, carl-august-sandburg

In the poem [A Father to His Son](https://www.familyfriendpoems.com/poem/a-father-to-his-son-by-carl-sandburg), the poet says, "**Time as a stuff can be wasted**'. In most of the summaries of this poem, it is mentioned that the poet says that time can be wasted *as if the poet advocated the point that wasting of time is not wrong.*

Is this interpretation correct? I wonder how anyone would advocate it.

I think the poet says that time can be wasted *if it were just a stuff,* and since it is not so it can't be wasted.

Is my perception right? I seek clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The poet contrasts two types of advice a father might give his son. The first type of advice is represented by the quote "Life is hard; be steel; be a rock." The poet then proposes an alternative type of advice, introduced by the quote "Life is a soft loam; be gentle; go easy."

The first type of advice is expanded in lines such as "Tell him too much money has killed men", which probably implies not wasting money. Not wasting time would fit into the same mindset: "work hard, don't waste money, don't waste time, be tough, be serious".

This mindset is contrasted with the one the poet proposes, which includes the lines,

> Tell him time as a stuff can be wasted.
>   Tell him to be a fool every so often
>   and to have no shame over having been a fool

The poet is indeed saying that one should not beat oneself up over time that appears to have been wasted. However, when one reads one, the poet does not seem to simply say that wasting time is good; instead, he appears to be saying that spending time on what turns out to be a folly is not wasted *when one learns a lesson from it*:

> yet learning something out of every folly
>   hoping to repeat none of the cheap follies
>   thus arriving at intimate understanding
>   of a world numbering many fools.

Seeing such follies as wasted time seems to represent the first mindset, which the poet rejects.

Comment: Thank you. What could be the fitting answer if the question is why the poet suggests that time can be wasted? Clarify please.

Comment: @BaskaranSoundararajan I explained this in my answer as follows: "spending time on what turns out to be a folly is not wasted when one learns a lesson from it".